# Should IDependencyResolver.GetServices using Unity return the default (unnamed) registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I've a question about the implementation of MVC's IDependencyResolver.GetServices when using Unity for the dependency injection.

There are several example implementations to be found, most of which have been implemented to work around the problem of Unity throwing exceptions when trying to resolve unregistered types.

Usualy GetServices is implemented like this:

```
IEnumerable<object> IDependencyResolver.GetServices(Type serviceType)
{
    try
    {
        return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<object>();
    }
}
```

What is of concern to me, and I have been unable to find any confirmation either way, is that ResolveAll does not return the default (unnamed) registration. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650505.aspx).

The documentation for [IDependencyResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver.getservices.aspx) does not make the same statement.

Does anyone know whether IDependencyResolver.GetServices should return all registered instances or just the named instances (using Unity parlance)?

Comment: I am getting weird results when using this approach with NHibernate. Did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: Not really, there were some other answers but it looks like they have been deleted.

Comment: Well .. part of the problem might be that your post is missing the "question" part.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. I hope this will work.

```
return (serviceType.IsClass && !serviceType.IsAbstract) ||        _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.ResolveAll(serviceType) : new object[] {};
```